# Partial String Search along with Multiple Word in AWS Elastic Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have started using AWS Elastic Search Service and I want to search in JSON array object with partial string search along with Multiple word search.

For example I have added the three objects in an array.

```
 [{
  "_id" : "1",
  "TitleKeywords" : "Game of thrones"
},
{
  "_id" : "2",
  "TitleKeywords" : "Baywatch"
},
{
  "_id" : "3",
  "TitleKeywords" : "Spider Man"
}]
```

Now I want to perform search on field name TitleKeywords and I want to search for partial word also search on multiple words.

Like for example, If I want to search 'Spi' character then it should results me into below JSON object.

```
{
 "_id" : "3",
 "TitleKeywords" : "Spider Man"
}
```

I have searched query syntax for this and found below query :

```
query: {
            query_string: {
                default_field: "TitleKeywords",
                query: "*Spi*"
         }
     }
```

Also, for search keyword 'Spider M' (which is a multiple word search) it should result me into below JSON object :

```
{
 "_id" : "3",
 "TitleKeywords" : "Spider Man"
}
```

Now, if I want to search on multiple words then I can use below query :

```
query: {
 match: {
         "TitleKeywords": {
            "query":    "Spider M",
            "operator": "and"
          }
       }
     }
```

I want my result to be the mixture of both query which results into partial string search on multiple words.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using combination of [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers) with [NGram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html).

So you are adding ngram field to your `"TitleKeywords"` and querying this way:

```
query: {
  match: {
    "TitleKeywords.ngram": {
      "query"   : "Spider M",
      "operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

But NGram-ing from 1 char can be ineffective so I'm not sure if this suits your needs.